# Wordpress: Overwriting Shortcode in Plugin

Tags: wordpress, svg

We are using a theme that directs plugins to generate the Builder/Shortcodes. A client doesn't like default look of the section separators, and I've build my own SVG and I have a path ready to go, however, I'm at a loss as to how to overwrite it. I'm thinking the if-statements and class_exists works into the solution, but again at a loss to how.

This is the code for the shortcode construction:

```
 <?php

if ( fusion_is_element_enabled( 'fusion_section_separator' ) ) {

if ( ! class_exists( 'FusionSC_SectionSeparator' ) ) {
    /**
     * Shortcode class.
     *
     * @package fusion-builder
     * @since 1.0
     */
    class FusionSC_SectionSeparator extends Fusion_Element {

        /**
         * An array of the shortcode arguments.
         *
         * @access protected
         * @since 1.0.0
         * @var array
         */
        protected $args;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         */
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            add_filter( 'fusion_attr_section-separator-shortcode', array( $this, 'attr' ) );
            add_filter( 'fusion_attr_section-separator-shortcode-icon', array( $this, 'icon_attr' ) );
            add_filter( 'fusion_attr_section-separator-shortcode-divider-candy', array( $this, 'divider_candy_attr' ) );
            add_filter( 'fusion_attr_section-separator-shortcode-divider-candy-arrow', array( $this, 'divider_candy_arrow_attr' ) );
            add_filter( 'fusion_attr_section-separator-shortcode-divider-rounded-split', array( $this, 'divider_rounded_split_attr' ) );
            add_filter( 'fusion_attr_section-separator-shortcode-divider-svg', array( $this, 'divider_svg_attr' ) );

            add_shortcode( 'fusion_section_separator', array( $this, 'render' ) );

        }

        /**
         * Render the shortcode
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         * @param  array  $args    Shortcode parameters.
         * @param  string $content Content between shortcode.
         * @return string          HTML output.
         */
        public function render( $args, $content = '' ) {

            global $fusion_settings;

            $defaults = FusionBuilder::set_shortcode_defaults(
                array(
                    'divider_type'     => 'triangle',
                    'divider_position' => 'center',
                    'hide_on_mobile'   => fusion_builder_default_visibility( 'string' ),
                    'class'            => '',
                    'id'               => '',
                    'backgroundcolor'  => $fusion_settings->get( 'section_sep_bg' ),
                    'bordersize'       => $fusion_settings->get( 'section_sep_border_size' ),
                    'bordercolor'      => $fusion_settings->get( 'section_sep_border_color' ),
                    'divider_candy'    => 'top',
                    'icon'             => '',
                    'icon_color'       => $fusion_settings->get( 'icon_color' ),
                ), $args
            );

            $defaults['bordersize'] = FusionBuilder::validate_shortcode_attr_value( $defaults['bordersize'], 'px' );

            extract( $defaults );

            $this->args = $defaults;

            if ( $icon ) {
                if ( ! $icon_color ) {
                    $this->args['icon_color'] = $bordercolor;
                }

                $icon = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-icon' ) . '></div>';
            }

            $candy = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-candy-arrow' ) . '></div><div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-candy' ) . '></div>';

            if ( false !== strpos( $this->args['divider_candy'], 'top' ) && false !== strpos( $this->args['divider_candy'], 'bottom' ) ) {
                $candy = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-candy' ) . '></div>';
            }

            if ( 'triangle' === $divider_type ) {
                $html = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode' ) . '>' . $icon . $candy . '</div>';
            } elseif ( 'bigtriangle' === $divider_type ) {
                $candy = '<svg id="bigTriangleCandy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-svg' ) . '>';

                if ( 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                    if ( 'right' === $divider_position ) {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 100 L75 0 L100 100 Z"></path>';
                    } elseif ( 'left' === $divider_position ) {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 100 L25 2 L100 100 Z"></path>';
                    } else {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 100 L50 2 L100 100 Z"></path>';
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( 'right' === $divider_position ) {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M-1 -1 L75 99 L101 -1 Z"></path>';
                    } elseif ( 'left' === $divider_position ) {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 -1 L25 100 L101 -1 Z"></path>';
                    } else {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M-1 -1 L50 99 L101 -1 Z"></path>';
                    }
                }

                $candy .= '</svg>';
                $html = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode' ) . '>' . $candy . '</div>';
            } elseif ( 'slant' === $divider_type ) {
                $candy = '<svg class="slantCandy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none" ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-svg' ) . '>';

                if ( 'left' === $divider_position && 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                    $candy .= '<path d="M100 -1 L100 100 L0 0 Z"></path>';
                } elseif ( 'right' === $divider_position && 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                    $candy .= '<path d="M0 100 L0 -1 L100 0 Z"></path>';
                } elseif ( 'right' === $divider_position && 'bottom' === $divider_candy ) {
                    $candy .= '<path d="M100 0 L-2 100 L101 100 Z"></path>';
                } else {
                    $candy .= '<path d="M0 0 L0 99 L100 99 Z"></path>';
                }
                $candy .= '</svg>';
                $html = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode' ) . '>' . $candy . '</div>';
            } elseif ( 'rounded-split' === $divider_type ) {
                $candy = sprintf( '<div %s></div>', FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-rounded-split' ) );
                $html = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode' ) . '>' . $candy . '</div>';
            } elseif ( 'big-half-circle' === $divider_type ) {
                $candy = '<svg id="bigHalfCircleCandy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-svg' ) . '>';

                if ( 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                    $candy .= '<path d="M0 100 C40 0 60 0 100 100 Z"></path>';
                } else {
                    $candy .= '<path d="M0 0 C55 180 100 0 100 0 Z"></path>';
                }

                $candy .= '</svg>';
                $html = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode' ) . '>' . $candy . '</div>';
            } elseif ( 'curved' === $divider_type ) {
                $candy = '<svg id="curvedCandy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-svg' ) . '>';

                if ( 'left' === $divider_position ) {
                    if ( 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>';
                    } else {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 0 C 20 100 50 100 100 0 Z"></path>';
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 100 C 60 0 75 0 100 100 Z"></path>';
                    } else {
                        $candy .= '<path d="M0 0 C 50 100 80 100 100 0 Z"></path>';
                    }
                }

                $candy .= '</svg>';
                $html = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode' ) . '>' . $candy . '</div>';
            } elseif ( 'clouds' === $divider_type ) {
                $candy = '<svg id="cloudsCandy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode-divider-svg' ) . '>';
                $candy .= '<path d="M-5 100 Q 0 20 5 100 Z"></path>
                            <path d="M0 100 Q 5 0 10 100"></path>
                            <path d="M5 100 Q 10 30 15 100"></path>
                            <path d="M10 100 Q 15 10 20 100"></path>
                            <path d="M15 100 Q 20 30 25 100"></path>
                            <path d="M20 100 Q 25 -10 30 100"></path>
                            <path d="M25 100 Q 30 10 35 100"></path>
                            <path d="M30 100 Q 35 30 40 100"></path>
                            <path d="M35 100 Q 40 10 45 100"></path>
                            <path d="M40 100 Q 45 50 50 100"></path>
                            <path d="M45 100 Q 50 20 55 100"></path>
                            <path d="M50 100 Q 55 40 60 100"></path>
                            <path d="M55 100 Q 60 60 65 100"></path>
                            <path d="M60 100 Q 65 50 70 100"></path>
                            <path d="M65 100 Q 70 20 75 100"></path>
                            <path d="M70 100 Q 75 45 80 100"></path>
                            <path d="M75 100 Q 80 30 85 100"></path>
                            <path d="M80 100 Q 85 20 90 100"></path>
                            <path d="M85 100 Q 90 50 95 100"></path>
                            <path d="M90 100 Q 95 25 100 100"></path>
                            <path d="M95 100 Q 100 15 105 100 Z"></path>';
                $candy .= '</svg>';
                $html = '<div ' . FusionBuilder::attributes( 'section-separator-shortcode' ) . '>' . $candy . '</div>';
            }

            return $html;

        }

        /**
         * Builds the attributes array.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         * @return array
         */
        public function attr() {

            global $fusion_settings;

            $attr = fusion_builder_visibility_atts(
                $this->args['hide_on_mobile'], array(
                    'class' => 'fusion-section-separator section-separator',
                )
            );

            $attr['style'] = '';

            if ( 'triangle' === $this->args['divider_type'] ) {
                if ( $this->args['bordercolor'] ) {
                    if ( 'bottom' === $this->args['divider_candy'] ) {
                        $attr['style'] = 'border-bottom:' . $this->args['bordersize'] . ' solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';';

                    } elseif ( 'top' === $this->args['divider_candy'] ) {
                        $attr['style'] = 'border-top:' . $this->args['bordersize'] . ' solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';';

                    } elseif ( false !== strpos( $this->args['divider_candy'], 'top' ) && false !== strpos( $this->args['divider_candy'], 'bottom' ) ) {
                        $attr['style'] = 'border:' . $this->args['bordersize'] . ' solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';';
                    }
                }
            } elseif ( 'bigtriangle' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'slant' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'big-half-circle' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'clouds' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'curved' === $this->args['divider_type'] ) {
                $attr['style'] = 'padding:0;';
            }

            if ( 'rounded-split' === $this->args['divider_type'] ) {
                $attr['class'] .= ' rounded-split-separator';
            }

            if ( $this->args['class'] ) {
                $attr['class'] .= ' ' . $this->args['class'];
            }

            if ( $this->args['id'] ) {
                $attr['id'] = $this->args['id'];
            }

            global $fusion_fwc_type, $fusion_col_type;

            if ( ! empty( $fusion_fwc_type ) ) {
                $margin_left  = $fusion_fwc_type['padding']['left'];
                $margin_right = $fusion_fwc_type['padding']['right'];
                if ( isset( $fusion_col_type['type'] ) && '1_1' !== $fusion_col_type['type'] ) {
                    $margin_left  = fusion_builder_single_dimension( $fusion_col_type['padding'], 'left' );
                    $margin_right = fusion_builder_single_dimension( $fusion_col_type['padding'], 'right' );
                }
                $margin_left_unitless  = (int) filter_var( $margin_left, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION );
                $margin_right_unitless = (int) filter_var( $margin_right, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION );

                $container_percentage  = 100 - $margin_left_unitless - $margin_right_unitless;
                if ( false !== strpos( $margin_left, '%' ) ) {
                    $margin_left_unitless_scaled = $margin_left_unitless / $container_percentage * 100;
                }

                if ( false !== strpos( $margin_right, '%' ) ) {
                    $margin_right_unitless_scaled = $margin_right_unitless / $container_percentage * 100;
                }

                $viewport_width = '100vw';

                if ( 'Boxed' === $fusion_settings->get( 'layout' ) ) {
                    $viewport_width = $fusion_settings->get( 'site_width' );
                }

                if ( 'Top' !== $fusion_settings->get( 'header_position' ) ) {
                    $viewport_width = $viewport_width . ' - ' . intval( $fusion_settings->get( 'side_header_width' ) ) . 'px';
                }

                // 100% width template && non 100% interior width container.
                if ( $fusion_fwc_type['width_100_percent'] && 'contained' === $fusion_fwc_type['content'] && ( isset( $fusion_col_type['type'] ) && '1_1' === $fusion_col_type['type'] ) ) {

                    // Both container paddings use px.
                    if ( false !== strpos( $margin_left, 'px' ) && false !== strpos( $margin_right, 'px' ) ) {
                        $margin_unit = 'px';
                        $margin_difference_half = abs( $margin_left_unitless - $margin_right_unitless ) / 2 . $margin_unit;

                        if ( 'Boxed' === $fusion_settings->get( 'layout' ) ) {
                            $margin_left_negative = '-' . $margin_left;
                            $margin_right_negative = '-' . $margin_right;
                        } else {
                            if ( $margin_left_unitless > $margin_right_unitless ) {
                                $margin_left  = '- ' . $margin_difference_half;
                                $margin_right = '+ ' . $margin_difference_half;
                            } elseif ( $margin_left_unitless < $margin_right_unitless ) {
                                $margin_left  = '+ ' . $margin_difference_half;
                                $margin_right = '- ' . $margin_difference_half;
                            } elseif ( $margin_left_unitless === $margin_right_unitless ) {
                                $margin_left  = '';
                                $margin_right = '';
                            }

                            $margin_left_negative = 'calc( (' . $viewport_width . ' - 100% ) / -2 ' . $margin_left . ' )';
                            $margin_right_negative = 'calc( (' . $viewport_width . ' - 100% ) / -2  ' . $margin_right . ' )';
                        }
                        $attr['class'] .= ' fusion-section-separator-with-offset';

                        // Both container paddings use %.
                    } elseif ( false !== strpos( $margin_left, '%' ) && false !== strpos( $margin_right, '%' ) ) {

                        if ( 'Boxed' === $fusion_settings->get( 'layout' ) ) {
                            $margin_unit = '%';

                            $main_padding_unitless = filter_var( $fusion_settings->get( 'hundredp_padding' ), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION );
                            $main_padding_unit = str_replace( $main_padding_unitless, '', $fusion_settings->get( 'hundredp_padding' ) );

                            $margin_left_negative  = 'calc( ( 100% - ' . ( 2 * $main_padding_unitless ) . $main_padding_unit . ' ) * ' . ( -1 / 100 ) * $margin_left_unitless_scaled . ' )';
                            $margin_right_negative = 'calc( ( 100% - ' . ( 2 * $main_padding_unitless ) . $main_padding_unit . ' ) * ' . ( -1 / 100) * $margin_right_unitless_scaled . ' )';
                        } else {
                            $margin_unit = 'vw';
                            $margin_sum  = ' - ' . ( $margin_left_unitless + $margin_right_unitless ) . $margin_unit;

                            $margin_left_negative  = 'calc( (' . $viewport_width . ' - 100% ' . $margin_sum . ') / -2 - ' . $margin_left_unitless . $margin_unit . ' )';
                            $margin_right_negative = 'calc( (' . $viewport_width . ' - 100% ' . $margin_sum . ') / -2  - ' . $margin_right_unitless . $margin_unit . ' )';

                            $attr['class'] .= ' fusion-section-separator-with-offset';
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Mixed container padding units.
                        $margin_left_final = $margin_left;
                        if ( false !== strpos( $margin_left, '%' ) && 'Boxed' !== $fusion_settings->get( 'layout' ) ) {
                            $margin_left_final = $margin_left_unitless . 'vw';
                        }

                        $margin_right_final = $margin_right;
                        if ( false !== strpos( $margin_right, '%' ) && 'Boxed' !== $fusion_settings->get( 'layout' ) ) {
                            $margin_right_final = $margin_right_unitless . 'vw';
                        }

                        $margin_left_negative  = 'calc( (' . $viewport_width . ' - 100% - ' . $margin_left . ' - ' . $margin_right . ') / -2 - ' . $margin_left_final . ' )';
                        $margin_right_negative = 'calc( (' . $viewport_width . ' - 100% - ' . $margin_left . ' - ' . $margin_right . ') / -2 - ' . $margin_right_final . ' )';
                    }
                } else {
                    // Non 100% width template.
                    if ( false !== strpos( $margin_left, '%' ) ) {
                        $margin_left = $margin_left_unitless_scaled . '%';
                        if ( false !== strpos( $margin_right, '%' ) ) {
                            $margin_right = $margin_right_unitless_scaled . '%';
                        }

                        $margin_left_negative = 'calc( (100% + ' . $margin_left . ' + ' . $margin_right . ') * ' . $margin_left_unitless . ' / -100 )';
                    } else {
                        $margin_left_negative = '-' . $margin_left;
                    }

                    if ( false !== strpos( $margin_right, '%' ) ) {
                        $margin_right = $margin_right_unitless_scaled . '%';
                        if ( false !== strpos( $margin_left, '%' ) ) {
                            $margin_left = $margin_left_unitless_scaled . '%';
                        }

                        $margin_right_negative = 'calc( (100% + ' . $margin_left . ' + ' . $margin_right . ') * ' . $margin_right_unitless . ' / -100 )';
                    } else {
                        $margin_right_negative = '-' . $margin_right;
                    }
                }

                $attr['style'] .= 'margin-left:' . $margin_left_negative . ';';
                $attr['style'] .= 'margin-right:' . $margin_right_negative . ';';
            }

            return $attr;

        }

        /**
         * Builds the rounded split attributes array.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         * @return array
         */
        public function divider_svg_attr() {
            $attr = array();

            if ( 'bigtriangle' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'slant' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'big-half-circle' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'clouds' === $this->args['divider_type'] || 'curved' === $this->args['divider_type'] ) {
                $attr['style'] = sprintf( 'fill:%s;padding:0;', $this->args['backgroundcolor'] );
            }
            if ( 'slant' === $this->args['divider_type'] && 'bottom' === $this->args['divider_candy'] ) {
                $attr['style'] = sprintf( 'fill:%s;padding:0;margin-bottom:-3px;display:block', $this->args['backgroundcolor'] );
            }

            return $attr;
        }

        /**
         * Builds the rounded split attributes array.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         * @return array
         */
        public function divider_rounded_split_attr() {
            return array(
                'class' => 'rounded-split ' . $this->args['divider_candy'],
                'style' => 'background-color:' . $this->args['backgroundcolor'] . ';',
            );
        }

        /**
         * Builds the icon attributes array.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         * @return array
         */
        public function icon_attr() {

            $attr = array(
                'class' => 'section-separator-icon icon fa ' . FusionBuilder::font_awesome_name_handler( $this->args['icon'] ),
                'style' => 'color:' . $this->args['icon_color'] . ';',
            );

            if ( FusionBuilder::strip_unit( $this->args['bordersize'] ) > 1 ) {
                $divider_candy = $this->args['divider_candy'];
                if ( 'bottom' === $divider_candy ) {
                    $attr['style'] .= 'bottom:-' . ( FusionBuilder::strip_unit( $this->args['bordersize'] ) + 10 ) . 'px;top:auto;';
                } elseif ( 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                    $attr['style'] .= 'top:-' . ( FusionBuilder::strip_unit( $this->args['bordersize'] ) + 10 ) . 'px;';
                }
            }
            return $attr;

        }

        /**
         * Builds the divider attributes array.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         * @param array $args The arguments array.
         * @return array
         */
        public function divider_candy_attr( $args ) {

            $attr = array(
                'class' => 'divider-candy',
            );

            $divider_candy = ( $args ) ? $args['divider_candy'] : $this->args['divider_candy'];

            if ( 'bottom' === $divider_candy ) {
                $attr['class'] .= ' bottom';
                $attr['style'] = 'bottom:-' . ( FusionBuilder::strip_unit( $this->args['bordersize'] ) + 20 ) . 'px;border-bottom:1px solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';border-left:1px solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';';
            } elseif ( 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                $attr['class'] .= ' top';
                $attr['style'] = 'top:-' . ( FusionBuilder::strip_unit( $this->args['bordersize'] ) + 20 ) . 'px;border-bottom:1px solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';border-left:1px solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';';
                // Modern setup, that won't work in IE8.
            } elseif ( false !== strpos( $this->args['divider_candy'], 'top' ) && false !== strpos( $this->args['divider_candy'], 'bottom' ) ) {
                $attr['class'] .= ' both';
                $attr['style'] = 'background-color:' . $this->args['backgroundcolor'] . ';border:1px solid ' . $this->args['bordercolor'] . ';';
            }

            return $attr;

        }

        /**
         * Builds the divider-arrow attributes array.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0
         * @param array $args The arguments array.
         * @return array
         */
        public function divider_candy_arrow_attr( $args ) {

            $attr = array(
                'class' => 'divider-candy-arrow',
            );

            $divider_candy = ( $args ) ? $args['divider_candy'] : $this->args['divider_candy'];

            // For borders of size 1, we need to hide the border line on the arrow, thus we set it to 0.
            $arrow_position = FusionBuilder::strip_unit( $this->args['bordersize'] );
            if ( '1' == $arrow_position ) {
                $arrow_position = 0;
            }

            if ( 'bottom' === $divider_candy ) {
                $attr['class'] .= ' bottom';
                $attr['style'] = 'top:' . $arrow_position . 'px;border-top-color: ' . $this->args['backgroundcolor'] . ';';
            } elseif ( 'top' === $divider_candy ) {
                $attr['class'] .= ' top';
                $attr['style'] = 'bottom:' . $arrow_position . 'px;border-bottom-color: ' . $this->args['backgroundcolor'] . ';';
            }

            return $attr;

        }

        /**
         * Adds settings to element options panel.
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.1
         * @return array $sections Section Separator settings.
         */
        public function add_options() {

            return array(
                'section_separator_shortcode_section' => array(
                    'label'       => esc_html__( 'Section Separator Element', 'fusion-builder' ),
                    'description' => '',
                    'id'          => 'sectionseparator_shortcode_section',
                    'type'        => 'accordion',
                    'fields'      => array(
                        'section_sep_border_size' => array(
                            'label'       => esc_html__( 'Section Separator Border Size', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'description' => esc_html__( 'Controls the border size of the section separator.', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'id'          => 'section_sep_border_size',
                            'default'     => '1',
                            'type'        => 'slider',
                            'choices'     => array(
                                'min'  => '0',
                                'max'  => '50',
                                'step' => '1',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'section_sep_bg' => array(
                            'label'       => esc_html__( 'Section Separator Background Color', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'description' => esc_html__( 'Controls the background color of the section separator style.', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'id'          => 'section_sep_bg',
                            'default'     => '#f6f6f6',
                            'type'        => 'color-alpha',
                        ),
                        'section_sep_border_color' => array(
                            'label'       => esc_html__( 'Section Separator Border Color', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'description' => esc_html__( 'Controls the border color of the separator.', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'id'          => 'section_sep_border_color',
                            'default'     => '#f6f6f6',
                            'type'        => 'color-alpha',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }
    }
}

new FusionSC_SectionSeparator();

}
```